# Getting the most frequent value from an array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have an array like the following

```
String[] football_club = {"Barcelona", "Real Madrid", "Chelsea", "Real Madrid", "Barcelona", "Barcelona"};

//result
Sting result_club = "a value most in the array"
```

From the array above, the **"Barcelona"** which has a value which often exist in the array.
How coding to find the value that appears most frequently in an array?

Comment: help me to understand your trouble. Do you want to count the number of times a word is repeated in your array?

Comment: Please check this out. Hope it will help you. http://fruzenshtein.com/exercise-1/

Comment: You should provide more details as to [what you have tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) and where you are having problems.  Just asking for code to a problem may be considered off-topic on stackoverflow (See [the help-page about asking](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)).

Comment: @blackbelt: yes, and then one of value of array will show. can you help me. thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import java.util.HashMap;

/**
 * Created with IntelliJ IDEA.
 * User: Alexander.Iljushkin
 * Date: 23.10.13
 * Time: 11:32
 */
public class TestClass1 {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] football_club = {"Barcelona", "Real Madrid", "Chelsea", "Real Madrid", "Barcelona", "Barcelona"};
        HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        String tempStr;
        for (int i = 0; i < football_club.length; i++)
        {
            tempStr = football_club[i];
            if(map.containsKey(tempStr))
            {
                map.put(tempStr, map.get(tempStr) + 1);
            }
            else
            {
                map.put(tempStr,1);
            }
        }

        System.out.print(map.toString());
    }
}
```

Later you can use Comparator to sort items in map by `amount` as wrote below (it's just an example, change it in self-educational way:

```
public class Testing {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        HashMap<String,Double> map = new HashMap<String,Double>();
        ValueComparator bvc =  new ValueComparator(map);
        TreeMap<String,Double> sorted_map = new TreeMap<String,Double>(bvc);

        map.put("A",99.5);
        map.put("B",67.4);
        map.put("C",67.4);
        map.put("D",67.3);

        System.out.println("unsorted map: "+map);

        sorted_map.putAll(map);

        System.out.println("results: "+sorted_map);
    }
}

class ValueComparator implements Comparator<String> {

    Map<String, Double> base;
    public ValueComparator(Map<String, Double> base) {
        this.base = base;
    }

    // Note: this comparator imposes orderings that are inconsistent with equals.    
    public int compare(String a, String b) {
        if (base.get(a) >= base.get(b)) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return 1;
        } // returning 0 would merge keys
    }
}
```

then when you sorted your hashmap, just get the first key and this would be the most frequent key

Comment: @user1878292 changed the answer. then when you've sorted your hashmap, just get the first key and this would be the most frequent key

Comment: I got it, it's true. thank you very much for your answered :)

Answer (score 7):

You can make a `HashMap<String,Integer>`. If the String already appears in the map, increment it's *key* by one, otherwise, add it to the map.

For example:

```
put("Barcelona", 1);
```

Then, assume it's "Barcelona" again, you can do:

```
put("Barcelona", get("Barcelona") + 1);
```

Since the *key* of "Barcelona" is 1, now when you put it, the key will be 2.

Answer (score 2):

An other way : sort the array, then iterate on it to count successive common elements, and keep a track of the max count / corresponding element.
The sorting may be heavy (relatively), but I think hashmap access are of the same magnitude of complexity (O(n.log(n)).

Answer (score 1):

If performance does not matter:

```
        String[] football_club = {"Barcelona", "Real Madrid", "Chelsea", "Real Madrid", "Barcelona", "Barcelona"};              
        List<String> l = Arrays.asList(football_club);
        Set<String> s = new HashSet<String>(l);
        for (String key : s) {
            int count = Collections.frequency(l, key);
            System.out.println("Found '" + key + "' " + count + " times.");
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

This works perfectly, max is new variable used to store max count found, If two elements have same frequency String[] football_club = {"Chelsea","Chelsea", "Real Madrid", "Real Madrid", "Real Madrid", "Barcelona" ,"Chelsea"};

This Returns : Chelsea

```
private String getRepeatedString(String[] football_club) {
    List<String> List1 = Arrays.asList(football_club);
    HashMap<String, Integer> data = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    int max = 0;
    for (String string : List1) {
        int count = 1;
        if (data.containsKey(string)) {
            count = data.get(string) + 1;
            data.put(string, count);
        } else {
            data.put(string, 1);
        }
        if (max < count)
            max =count;
    }
    System.out.println(data);
    for (Entry<String, Integer> entry : data.entrySet()) {
        if (max == entry.getValue()) {
            return entry.getKey();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a new class which encapsulates a HashMap object.

Then you can deine your own put and get methods.